# Google map not visible in pop up due to a div styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, syncfusion

I have the following function to display a location in Google Map based on the coordinates.
The below function is called upon a button click:

```
function onClickLocate(args) {
    var gridInstance = $(args.target.closest(".e-grid")).ejGrid("instance");
    //get index of the row getIndexByRow() 
    var inx = gridInstance.getIndexByRow(args.target.closest("tr"));
    //CurrentViewData using Index 
    var data = gridInstance.getCurrentViewData()[inx]; 
    openMapDialog(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
}
```

openMapDialog opens a syncfusion pop up"

```
function openMapDialog(lat, lng) {
    $("body").append("<div id='branchMap'></div>");
    var divMAp = document.createElement('div');
    divMAp.id = "googleMap";
    $("#branchMap").append(divMAp);
    $('#googleMap').css("position", "initial");
    $("[data-upgraded]").removeAttr("data-upgraded");
    $("#branchMap").ejDialog({
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        minWidth: 310,
        minHeight: 215,
        enableModal: true,
        showOnInit: true,
        title: "Warehouse Location",
        open: "createMap",
        cssClass: "custom-dialog",
        isResponsive: true,
        target: "body"
    });
};
```

The createMap is a function found on StackOverflow to display the map:

```
function createMap(args) {
    document.getElementById('googleMap').style.display = "block";
    var lat =$("#branchMap").data("lat");
    var lng =$("#branchMap").data("lng");
    var map;
    var marker;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatlng,
        draggable: false
    });

    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': myLatlng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        }
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': marker.getPosition()
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The issue is that the map is being rendered in the chtml with the correct location in the pop up but it is not visible because of the styling of the googleMap div, the position is set to absolute
As you can see in the openMapDialog, I tried to set it to initial but I can't.
I know that position at initial will work since I tried it first in the Chrome DevTools.

Any idea of how to set the correct styling for the googleMap div?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it your divMAp has no dimensions, I guess simply setting width and height on divMAp to 100% will do the trick.

add the following two lines under divMAp.id = "googleMap";

```
divMAp.id = "googleMap";
divMAp.style.width = '100%';
divMAp.style.height = '100%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a height on the googleMap div to 100% or a hard-coded pixel amount. I had this issue before and it was because the div had no height so it looks invisible.